# How i can detect a single ARuco marker among several markers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, virtual-reality, augmented-reality

Hi everyone i am working on a rehabilitation application that depends on ARuco markers. The idea is to draw an object on a single marker among the four existing ones, then when the patient's hand reaches that marker, the object moves to the next marker, till finishing the exercise. I tried to do so via checking the marker id, and drawing only on it but it remains draw on all of them at the same time, here is the code:

```
// Detect markers
    std::vector<int> ids;
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > corners;
    cv::aruco::detectMarkers(image, marker_dict, corners, ids);

    // Draw markers using opencv tool
    cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(mid, corners, ids);

    // Draw markers custom
    for (size_t i = 0; i < corners.size(); ++i)
    {

        // Convert to integer ponits
        int num = static_cast<int>(corners[i].size());
        std::vector<cv::Point> points;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < corners[i].size(); ++j)
            points.push_back(cv::Point(static_cast<int>(corners[i][j].x), static_cast<int>(corners[i][j].y)));
        const cv::Point* pts = &(points[0]);

        
        // Draw
        
        
        if (ids.at(0) == 45) {
            cv::fillPoly(right, &pts, &num, 1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
        }
```

Comment: Your code seems to say "for each marker corner, if the 0th marker ID is 45, draw". Ie. You're not asking "if the marker *that this corner belongs to* has the ID 45". You're always just checking the 0th. Naturally, since you're doing the same check for every corner, you get the same result for every corner.

Comment: @DMGregory You mean to write the if statement outside the for loop?

Comment: Unless you've hidden a curly brace somewhere, it's inside the first for loop.

Comment: @DMGregory Moved it outside the for loop, but the same problem

Comment: The issue isn't placement in or outside the loop. The issue is that you've hard-coded this to only ever look at a single marker's ID.

Comment: No this is an example with the opencv library, and i only edited it. Can you help me to check a single marker id?

Comment: Presumably you tried `ids.at(i)`?

Comment: @DMGregory Wooow! It works well. Really many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking every marker's ID, you're only checking the ID of the first marker in the list. And you're re-checking that one marker when deciding whether to draw *every* marker.

Replace

```
if (ids.at(0) == 45) {
```

with

```
if (ids.at(i) == 45) {
```

to actually check whether *this* marker's ID is 45, before drawing it.

This is a very simple bit of programming that does not require game development expertise to solve (I don't even know C++!) - so you should really brush up on your language fundamentals and visit [our general programming sister site StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) for help with stuff like this.